# What other chat apps that can be integrated easily to cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, chat

Can you recommend a better chat apps that can be easily integrated to cakephp? Something like a facebook chat, can also be customize.

Thanks,

JRubins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few options:

- This jQuery chat module enables you to seamlessly integrate Gmail/Facebook style chat into your existing website: http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/
- 6 free ajax chat applications using PHP: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/09/free-ajax-chat-applications-php.html
- Building your own from scratch: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/